# How do I capture a direct reference to a list item for speed in Python?

Tags: python, list, object, optimization, micro-optimization

In Python, can I get some sort of direct reference to the value of one of the items in a list, such as `my_list[0][0]`?

Am using Python 3.7.2.

This: `direct = my_list[0][0]` does not work; while they both initially point to the same object, when `my_list[0][0]` is changed, Python changes the list object. `direct` points to the original object with the old value, and `my_list[0][0]` points to a new object with the new value. I'm looking for a way to have a direct pointer to the value in `my_list[0][0]` even after the value changes, without having to invoke the overhead of calling `my_list[0][0]`. (This may not be possible with lists?)

Code confirming the above:

```
my_list = [[0, 1],
        [0, 1]]

direct = my_list[0][0]

print(id(direct))
print(direct)
print(id(my_list[0][0]))
print(my_list[0][0])

my_list[0][0] = 10

print(id(direct))
print(direct)
print(id(my_list[0][0]))
print(my_list[0][0])
```

Output:

```
140706382385952
0
140706382385952
0
140706382385952
0
140706382386272
10
```

Why care? Speed.

I'm optimizing a simulation which stores data in nested lists. 
The lists are rarely accessed, except for one item: my_list[0][0]. This is a critical item for determining simulation flow, so it is checked extremely often.

Some test code indicates checking the value of this nested list item takes 1.6x times longer than a direct variable check. Because of the frequency, this is a dominant factor in run time.

Test code:

```
import time

my_list = [[0, 1],
        [0, 1]]
iterations = 100000000

before = time.time()
for i in range (iterations):
    if my_list[0][0] == 1 : break
after=time.time()

list_time = after - before
print("List check time: "+str(list_time))

before = time.time()
direct = my_list[0][0]
for i in range (iterations):
    if direct == 1 : break
after=time.time()

direct_time = after - before
print("Direct check time: "+str(direct_time))

print("Multiple: "+str(list_time/direct_time))
```

Output:

```
List check time: 13.461313247680664
Direct check time: 8.034856081008911
Multiple: 1.6753645755395248
```

Update: [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) suggested capturing a sub-list reference to `my_list[0]`; if the level-zero list assignment not does not change (and in my case, it does not), I can then refer to `sub_list[0]`, for a single dereference instead of a double dereference. A code check indicates a significant gain (setup same as above):

```
before = time.time()
sub_direct = my_list[0]
for i in range (iterations):
    if sub_direct[0] == 1 : break
after=time.time()

sub_direct_time = after - before
print("Sub-direct check time: "+str(sub_direct_time))

print("Multiple: "+str(sub_direct_time/direct_time))
```

Output:

```
Sub-direct check time: 8.609910488128662
Multiple: 1.2680250336804944
```

Depending on the run, seems to incur about half the performance penalty.

Comment: what python is this? 2/3?

Comment: ints are immutable.  If you change the element to be a mutable object, you'll be able to take a reference and use it directly.  That said, I doubt that'll help you solve your performance issue.  One thing I'd encourage you to look into is using numpy.

Comment: @DeepSpace he timed the entire loop not the single call.

Comment: @DeepSpace: Looks fine to me. Mental Nomad is timing 10^8 iterations, while you're picking the minimum of 10^4 separate tries of 10^4 iterations.

Comment: @NPE - thanks; I've tried this as a list of Tuples, which does the trick for referencing... but, as a Tuple, I can't change the value in [0][0]. I tried sticking a variable in as the first element in the Tuple, which also solves the reference problem and leaves the element mutable (yay!) but then I can't modify the variable when referring to it programmatically as [0][0] (which kinda ruins the point.)

Comment: @npe - +1 for NumPy reference. I looked into NumPy arrays for this project (which is what I believe you're referring to), but while NumPy arrays are faster when working with values in the array, I found in testing that they are slower for explicitly referencing and updating values in the array.

In this case, the nested lists are not really used for calculation; they are really just multi-dimensional storage, for which simple lists are faster than NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Not possible. Python references don't work like that. References always refer to objects, not to other references or to pieces of objects.

If you never reassign `list[0]`, then you *could* save a reference to that sublist, so you only have to do `sublist[0]`:

```
sublist = list[0]
...
do_whatever_with(sublist[0])  # instead of list[0][0]
```

Also, don't call your variables `list`. The `list` type has dibs on that name, and you'll get confused when you want to call `list` on something.

Comment: Or even if you're reassigning l[0][0] then also update your reference to that value, so that you could still benefit from faster lookups.

Comment: Point taken. 

I only used `list` in the "prover" demo code, not my real code, but I've gone back and edited my question to replace "list" with "my_list" to avoid confusion and to avoid setting bad examples.

Comment: @altunyurt - I considered that, but there are two downsides:
1. There are many level-zero lists, accessed programmatically. Capturing a new reference each time [0][0] changes requires lots of checks for whether [0] is the one being modified, sapping the speed savings. Unsure how badly.
2. Increased code maintenance overhead: the lists are accessed in various places in the code, which leads to more potential for error if I forget to update the reference in some particular part of code. I feel like the simulation is "near final," but I can expect future changes when needs change.